# bottle request.json getting a 405 on post

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest, bottle, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to get bottle to receive json in an xmlhttprequest and I'm getting a 405 error

Part of my bottle script:

```
@app.route('/myroute/')
def myroute():
    print request.json
```

Part of my other script to test the xhr out:

```
jdata = json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})
urllib2.urlopen("http://location/app/myroute/", jdata)
```

Why am I getting a 405?

```
bottlepy error: 127.0.0.1 - - [2012-09-23 23:09:34] "POST /myroute/ HTTP/1.0" 405 911 0.005458

urllib2 error: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed
```

I also tried variations of:

```
@app.route('/myroute/json:json#[1-9]+#')
def myroute(json):
    request.content_type = 'application/json'
    print request.json, json
```

Returning json does not seem to be an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the server does not allow POST requests. You can probably try sending it in a GET request instead:

```
urllib2.urlopen("http://location/app/myroute/?" + jdata)
```

---

**UPDATE**:

I just realized, after looking at your question again, that you are actually trying to send JSON data via GET request. You should in general avoid sending JSONs with GET requests, but use POST requests instead[[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body/978094#978094)].

To send a POST request to Bottle, you also need to [set the headers to `application/json`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/0.10/api.html?highlight=json#bottle.BaseRequest.json):

```
headers = {}
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
jdata = json.dumps({"foo":"bar"})
urllib2.urlopen("http://location/app/myroute/", jdata, headers)
```

Then, with the help of @Anton's answer, you can access the JSON data in your view like this:

```
@app.post('/myroute/')
def myroute():
    print request.json
```

Also, as a bonus, to send a normal GET request and access it:

```
# send GET request
urllib2.urlopen("http://location/app/myroute/?myvar=" + "test")

# access it 
@app.route('/myroute/')
def myroute():
    print request.GET['myvar'] # should print "test"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of these answers are correct! I am still having trouble getting request.json to show anything, but at least the server is not failing.

Comment: @scape I've updated my answer and hopefully it will answer your question :)

Comment: Yes it does, I also realized I needed to set the headers in urllib2 so I went with post and added headers, just as you suggested. Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `route` decorator makes the decorated function handle only GET requests. You need to add a `method` argument to tell Bottle to handle POST requests instead. To do that, you need to change:

```
@app.route('/myroute/')
```

to:

```
@app.route('/myroute/', method='POST')
```

or a shorter version:

```
@app.post('/myroute/')
```